# SQL Lookup List

Tags: sql, field, categories, lookup

I have been asked to create a table in SQL and am not sure about one of the table fields.

I have been asked to create a table with the following information:

- First Name
- Last Name
- Three Address Lines
- Mobile Phone
- Home Phone
- Date Modified
- Person Category
- Comment

This is the description for the Person Category:

> Person Category: 
>   Simple Lookup List contained in the database, (ID and Description), can pre-populate this data from the script, no need to edit and update from the VB application. Category descriptions are:  Client, Worker, Assessor, and Unknown.

Can someone please explain to me what is needed here?

**UPDATE**

Here is my current script for the Person table:

```
CREATE TABLE db_person.Person
(
PersonID NUMBER NOT NULL,
FirstName varchar(50) NOT NULL,
LastName varchar(50) NOT NULL,
AddressLine1 varchar(50),
AddressLine2 varchar(50),
AddressLine3 varchar(50),
MobilePhone varchar(20),
HomePhone varchar(20),
DateModified DATE,
PersonCategory varchar(50),
Comment varchar(8000),
PRIMARY KEY (PersonID)
)
```

Can I have some help to create the Lookup List for the PersonCategory and to link it into the Person Table?

Comment: From what i can gather is you need to create a database table with those fields that will be populated with data from a script.

Answer (score 0):

It means that you need to create another table for the Person Category. Thus a one-to-many relationship between the 2 tables.

Moreover because the description of a person is limited to either Client, Worker, Assessor or Unknown, you should be handle this in your script creation by using the keyword "CHECK".

i.e.

```
CHECK (Description in ("Client", "Worker", "Assessor", "Unknown"))
```

Comment: Can you please explain this check code? Does the code make sure that the value of Description has to be either "Client", "Worker", "Assessor" or "Unknown"? Can I place this code in a stored procedure for adding the values to the Person table to ensure that the PersonCategory has to be one of these values?

Comment: Yes indeed. This way you make sure that the column Description contains either "Client", "Worker", "Assessor" or "Unknown". nothing else. Even if you try to do a insert directly to the database without using any software.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you must create the Categories lookup table. You could create it with a script like this:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

SET ANSI_PADDING ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [Categories](
    [Id] [uniqueidentifier] ROWGUIDCOL  NOT NULL,
    [Description] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Categories] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

SET ANSI_PADDING ON
GO

ALTER TABLE [Categories] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_Categories_Id]  DEFAULT (newid()) FOR [Id]
GO
```

and populate it with the 4 descriptions:

```
INSERT INTO Categories ([Description])
VALUES ('Client')

INSERT INTO Categories ([Description])
VALUES ('Worker')

INSERT INTO Categories ([Description])
VALUES ('Assessor')

INSERT INTO Categories ([Description])
VALUES ('Unknown')
```

After that, you must create the Persons table, with the constraint with the Categories table:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

SET ANSI_PADDING ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [Persons](
    [Id] [uniqueidentifier] ROWGUIDCOL  NOT NULL,
    [IdCategory] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [FirstName] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [LastName] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [FirstAddress] [varchar](250) NULL,
    [SecondAddress] [varchar](250) NULL,
    [ThirdAddress] [varchar](250) NULL,
    [HomePhone] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [MobilePhone] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Modified] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [Comment] [varchar](500) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Persons] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

SET ANSI_PADDING ON
GO

ALTER TABLE [Persons] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_Persons_Id]  DEFAULT (newid()) FOR [Id]
GO

ALTER TABLE [Persons]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_Persons_Categories] FOREIGN KEY([IdCategory])
REFERENCES [Categories] ([Id])
GO

ALTER TABLE [Persons] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_Persons_Categories]
GO
```

Now you have the two tables :)

These scripts run on Microsoft SQL Server.

PS: Best practice is to do another table for multiple addresses and multiple phones ;)

To retrieve data with the SELECT, you could do:

```
SELECT FirstName, LastName, Description AS Category
FROM Persons INNER JOIN
Categories ON Categories.Id = Persons.IdCategory
```

If you're using NUMBER for the IDs, change the IdCategory datatype in NUMBER. After that, the storedprocedure could be like:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [AddPerson]
(
 @Category varchar(50),
 @FirstName varchar(50),
 @LastName varchar(50),
 @FirstAddress varchar(250) = NULL,
 @SecondAddress varchar(250) = NULL,
 @ThirdAddress varchar(250) = NULL,
 @HomePhone varchar(50) = NULL,
 @MobilePhone varchar(50) = NULL,
 @Comment varchar(500) = NULL
)
AS BEGIN
 Declare @idCategory NUMBER
 Set @idCategory = SELECT Id FROM Categories WHERE Description = Category

 INSERT INTO Persons ([IdCategory], [FirstName], [LastName],
    [FirstAddress],
    [SecondAddress],
    [ThirdAddress],
    [HomePhone],
    [MobilePhone],
    [Modified],
    [Comment])
 VALUES (@idCategory,
    @FirstName,
    @LastName,
    @FirstAddress,
    @SecondAddress,
    @ThirdAddress,
    @HomePhone,
    GETDATE(),
    @MobilePhone,
    @Comment)

END

GO
```

I'm sorry if this codes contains some errors but I wrote it with notepad :)

Comment: Thanks. I am wanting to use a stored procedure code to insert values into the Persons table, what values do I use for the PersonCategory? What name do I use, and what datatype?

Comment: I edited my answer with the Stored Procedure, because I couldn't write too characters in this comment ;) Check it :)